# Why does resource.data in Firestore rules work incorrectly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have issue with allowing user to `read` data with such rule:

[image]

Here I check if authenticated user is either sender or receiver.

Here's message sample:

[image]

Here's users collection:

[image]

Problem is that such rule does not work. Even with one of two conditions it fails.

It actually doesn't even see the properties `fromUser` and `toUser` in `resource.data`.

But on tests it allows to read:

[image]
[image]

Can you please tell me where I have mistaken, cause I don't get why I can't access both `resource.data.fromUser` and `resource.data.toUser` in Firestore rules? (I am using firebase authentication via Google)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what query you run in the rules simulator and also a complete screenshot of document so we can compare the IDs

Comment: @MichaelLearner How do you fetch the doocument? From the DocumentReference or via a Query? Can you share the code?

Comment: Can you try logging user's UID before your query and ensure user is logged in?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I use `react-firebase-hooks v3` and query data from there it looks like:
 
`const [messages, messagesLoading] = useCollectionData(
    firestore
      .collection("messages")
      .where("access", "==", hashId)
      .orderBy("createdAt")
  );`
I removed some fields of message from the question to specify the issue. But if I try to set rule for `message` from messages collection it works fine. I don't get why it doesn't get value of sender and receiver

Comment: @Dharmaraj If I set `request.auth.uid != null" it works correctly too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question and comment, you are facing the limitation that "[Rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters)".

Your query "**must follow the constraints set by your security rules**" so it means that it should filter on the `fromUser` or on the `toUser` fields, which is not the case with:

```
firestore.collection("messages").where("access", "==", hashId).orderBy("createdAt")
```

*(Query from your comment above)*

---

Note that your simulation in the "Rules Playground" works because you are fetching **one document**, (by its ID, see field `Location`), which follows the constraints set by your security rules

---

Finally, to make it easier to write your query, I would add in the `message` doc a field of type Array that contains both the IDs of the `fromUser` and `toUser`. This way you can query with `array-contains` and also simplify your security rule with the [`in`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) operator.

Comment: updated with `users array` on message doc, but still the same error, even recreated indexes, `request.auth.uid` works fine, but when I try to do `if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users` it doesn't work the way I want.  Also I updated query: added there `array-contains` and after searched for `uid` of message(user who created the message. I did in such way cause I cannot use more than one `array-contains` in one query). I really don't get why it doesn't read values, maybe it is some bug or I misses something:(

Comment: Can you share your new query and new security rules: pls update your question

Comment: I've reset the rule just for `request.auth != null` now. But when I did as you said, I got the same error using array of users and query : `firestore.collection("messages").where("users", "array-contains", userDialogueId).where("uid", "==", userCurrent.uid).orderBy("createdAt")`. Created index for that query, but still the same result. Rule there was: `: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.users`. Firebase like accesses some properties of my message doc, but doesn't do with another, so in both cases I couldn't reach wanted data:(

Comment: What happens if you do `firestore.collection("messages").where("users", "array-contains", userDialogueId)`

Comment: I've tried it, the same error. But the way I see my issue is just purely connected with Firestore rules, it just doesn't read wanted data.  For instance, if I put in rule `: if resource.data.hashId == "534543"` (hashId is special id for identifying 2 users chatting) it works fine and reads proper values and works correctly. But with wanted data connected with users it just doesn't give it:(

Comment: TBH it is difficult to follow you: you are mentioning new variable names in each of your comments :-) Can you set up a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  and share the entire code (query and security rules) in you original question, not as comments.

Comment: Thanks! I've played around with rules and how to properly bind them to my query and figured out the solution:)

Comment: @MichaelLearner can you please share your solution or a summary of it?